# how do you find out which annotations are in which spring version?

Tags: spring

How do you find out which annotations are in which spring versions?

Comment: I don't believe you will find a definitive list by version, though the Reference Documentation for each might give you some guidance (https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#learn).

Comment: OK I will take a look at it.  Thank you!